# Renaming react native example app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to work from this example App:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/tree/master/Example

But when I rename the following lines:

`index.ios.js`

```
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

`index.android.js`

```
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

I have rename `Example.js` to `App.js` and updated the content:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router createReducer={reducerCreate} getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle}>
        //...
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But when I try to compile the app I receive the following error.

```
Application Example has not been registered.
This is either due to a require() error during initialisation or failure to call AppRegistery.registerComponent.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the name attribute in `package.json`
2. run react-native upgrade
3. change your Appregistry `AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);`

Comment: Hey @kenitive I forgot to mention I have already updated the `package.json` but all that aside the project does not seem to have updated it is still referencing `Example` in the error.  Also why the rename from `App` to `MyApp`.