# How to rename project react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to rename a [React Native boilerplate](https://github.com/AmitM30/react-native-typescript-boilerplate) to `myApp`. I'm following [this renaming guide](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/how-to-rename-a-react-native-app-dafd92161c35) as instructed by the boilerplate repo, doing the following after running `npm install` in the cloned project:

1. Change `displayName` in app.json
2. Delete ios/ and android/ directories, run `react-native eject`
3. Run `react-native link`

However, when I try to run the app with `react-native run-android`, I get the error:

> Application myApp has not been registered

What am I doing wrong? This is pretty much the same question as [Renaming react native example app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477020/renaming-react-native-example-app), but there hasn't been an accepted answer (I've tried the given one, changing the name in package.json and running react-native upgrade to no avail)

Edit: I did some more testing, and I found that whenever I delete /android and /ios, and `react-native eject`, I get the same error. So the issue is not specific to renaming the app, but the eject.

Comment: Is you registerComponent like this: AppRegistry.registerComponent('old_name', () => new_name_you_want); ? Also run `react-native upgrade` after deleting the `android` and `ios` folders

Comment: please check : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this can help you [react-native-rename](https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename), it's pretty easy to use

steps:

- `react-native-rename "New Name"`
- `react-native run-android -- --reset-cache`

to change package name (only for android) do

`react-native-rename "New Name" -b com.company.appname`

Comment: After renaming your project you should clean, build, and reinstall third party dependencies to get it running properly with the new name

Comment: Added more details to the answer. Or look at @IftekharDani bellow answer

Answer (score 0):

**Below steps may help you to rename project:**

> Tested on my machine

```
Step 1: git clone https://github.com/AmitM30/react-native-typescript-boilerplate.git
Step 2: sudo npm install -g react-native-rename
Step 3: cd react-native-typescript-boilerplate/
Step 4: npm install
Step 5: react-native-rename “Name of the app which you want to do”
Step 6: watchman watch-del-all
Step 7: npm start --reset-cache
Step 8: react-native run-ios (For Running IOS app in IOS emulator)
Step 9: react-native run-android (For Running Android app in Android emulator)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to rename your project name then follow this step:

1] open file
file location:

```
android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

2] change here to add your wanted project name:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">LoanApp</string><---hehe LoanApp name to change your project name 
</resources>
```